# NSView outside of NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I have an NSWindow and basically, what I am trying to pop up an NSWindow outside of the bounds of the NSWindow it's in every time a user hovers over the NSWindow.

But every time I try to do that, since the NSView is outside of the bounds of NSWindow it gets cut off.

Here's a picture of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a borderless `NSWindow`, large enough to contain your view, and make the window a child window of the main window it's attached to. To make a window a child of another window, you use the `addChildWindow:ordered:` method of `NSWindow`.

Child windows are attached to the parent window and will move with their parent window when the parent window moves. If you just open a new window without making it a child window, it will be "left behind" if the other window is moved.

To make a borderless window, pass `NSBorderlessWindowMask` as the `styleMask` to the `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` method of `NSWindow`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to create another `NSWindow` with no border and put the button in that.